# WASM WebAssembly FileNotFoundException from System.Private.CoreLib

Tags: .net-core, .net-standard, uno-platform

I am trying to use https://platform.uno/ to build some tools. The WASM (WebAssembly)-Project from uno-platform template will not start due to FileNotFoundExceptions regarding some base Microsoft libs.
I created a new uno-platform APP from uno template. I have updated all NuGet packages to latest version. When I start the wasm web-project I get the following exceptions (at bootstrap i guess):

[image: FileNotFoundException]

followed by:
[image: FileNotFoundException]

followed by:
[image: WTF]

Here you can see the Exception class comes from the namespace that was not found in picture 1. It's very strange to me and I don't know whats up anymore.
I guess this is an issue with prerequisites or wrong versions in dependencies somewhere. Does anybody know whats up?

Here is the csproj of the WASM project:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <WasmHead>true</WasmHead>
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);__WASM__</DefineConstants>
    <NoWarn>NU1701</NoWarn>
    <StartupObject>Macs3.Calculations.TestTool.Wasm.Program</StartupObject>
 <MonoRuntimeDebuggerEnabled>true</MonoRuntimeDebuggerEnabled> 
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\Macs3.Calculations.TestTool.UWP\Assets\*.png" Link="Assets\%(FileName)%(Extension)" />
    <Content Include="Fonts\winjs-symbols.woff2" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="WasmCSS\Fonts.css" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="WasmScripts\AppManifest.js" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <LinkerDescriptor Include="LinkerConfig.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- 
    This item group is required by the project templace because of the
    new SDK-Style project, otherwise some files are not aded automatically.
    
    You can safely remove this ItemGroup completely.
    -->
    <Compile Remove="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Content Include="LinkerConfig.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Uno.UI" Version="1.46.0-dev.2039" />
    <PackageReference Include="Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap" Version="1.0.0-dev.298" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="..\Macs3.Calculations.TestTool.Shared\Macs3.Calculations.TestTool.Shared.projitems" Label="Shared" Condition="Exists('..\Macs3.Calculations.TestTool.Shared\Macs3.Calculations.TestTool.Shared.projitems')" />
</Project>
```

Comment: Which version specificity? Can you please try the latest prerelease builds as WASM is in active development.

Comment: Do you have dotnet core 3 installed ? You should try to put a `global.json` file and force the .net core to 2.2.x version instead.
You may also try to launch using CTRL-F5 insteald of F5 because the VS debugger won't work on Wasm projects.